# Normal distribution: Find the range of masses, symmetrical about the mean, such that 50% of the eggs are within this range.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, symmetry

A particular breed of hen produces eggs with a mean mass of $60$ grams and a standard deviation of $4$ grams and mass is found to be normally distributed.

Eggs are classified as small if their mass is less than $55$g.

> a. Find the proportion of eggs that are not classified as small.

I've worked out the first part. I did $(55-60)/4=-1.25$. Then I found the $Z$-score which was $0.89435$, and then $\times100$ to get $89.435\%$.

> b. Find the range of masses, symmetrical about the mean, such that $50\%$ of the eggs are within this range.

I don’t understand how to get to the second part; I just don’t understand how you find the range of masses that are within $50\%$. I understand that it will be $25\%$ on each side, I just don’t know how to work it out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This looks a lot like a homework problem — can you show us what you’ve tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Iv worked out the first part, I did 55-60 /4 which got me -1.25. Then I found the Z score which was 0.89435 and then X 100 to get 89.435. I don’t understand how to get to the second part.

Comment: The Z score is the (signed) number of standard deviations from the mean (-1.25) the probability is .89. Sounds like you did that part right so what is different about b?

Comment: I just don’t understand how u find the range of masses that are within 50%

Comment: The hint here is “symmetrical about the mean”

Comment: I understand that it will be 25% on each side, I just don’t know how to work it out.

Comment: Use z score tables to find the z score that has 25 percent

Comment: Hi, I found that the z score for 25% is -0.674, please could you point me in the right direction In what to do next

Comment: do you know the meaning of what you found in your above comment? It’s the number of standard deviations below the mean that equals the 25th percentile of the normal distribution— you indicated that you know you need 25% on both sides of the mean — so you’ve found half your answer. What percentile would give you 25% above the mean?

Comment: 75%, find the z score for 0.75 ?

Comment: Yep :-) If you understand why then I think you get how to work with the standard normal an what z-scores mean/how to use. I’d review this with your professor and/or study group because these types of calculations are essential to making progress in basic probability and statistics.

Answer (score 1):

So the entire HW problem here is about how to work with the standard normal distribution and it's CDF.

The key to solving these problems is knowing what the probability associated with each $z-$score represents. For example, $z=1.96$ is the $97.5$th percentile, which is used to construct confidence intervals and two-sided rejection regions with confidence/significance level $0.05$.

In general, if you have some interval $(a,b)$ and want to know $P(X \in (a,b))$ then if $X$ is normally distributed, you calculate the $z-$score for $a$ and $b$ so you can look up the correct probabilities:

$z_a = \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}, z_b = \frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$

The z-score gives the number of standard deviations away from the mean. The probability that a normally distributed random variable is within $z$ standard deviations of it's mean is: $P(X \leq \mu + z\sigma) - P(X \leq \mu - z\sigma)$